# How soon does a magic item (Ring, Amulet, scarf, etc) work on a character?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Are players able to swap out magic items continually and get the immediate effect of their enchantment?

Example: A character has a Ring of Transportation, Ring of Protection, and a Ring of Invisibility. Can they swap them around all within the same day/encounter to get the benefit?

I was under the assumption that magic items needed to be worn for 24 hours before they work, but this could be an old rule that never translated to Pathfinder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While some *Pathfinder* magic items *do* need to be carried or worn for some period of time before their full benefits are realized, unless the magic item specifically says in its description that it must be, it does *not* need to be, and all of its benefits can be realized immediately by the next lucky fellow to pick it up or don it, and it can be passed around from person to person at will.

For example, the [*headband of vast intelligence*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-vast-intelligence/) has a noticeable but still lesser effect until its been worn by the same creature for 24 hours and the [*ring of sustenance*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance/) must be worn continuously by the same creature for a week before its effects kick in at all, but the *rings of [invisibility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-invisibility)*, [*protection*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-protection), and [*transposition*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-transposition) can benefit their wearers right away… although such a wearer must still discover the command word necessary to activate the *ring of invisibility* or *ring of transposition*.

The idea that magic items need time to attune to a new possessor is, to my understanding, a more *modern* rule, largely *atypical* of magic items in *Pathfinder* and its antecedents, although several late-era [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) magic items also require such a warm-up period.

Comment: You should add that while some items do grant their bonus immediately, the bonus can also change after being worn, such as in the case of stat boosting items.

Comment: Headband of Vast Intelligence is one of the best examples of items that DO change their function slightly after longer wear. Also, I believe 4th ed also used some sort of attunement mechanic.

Comment: @YogoZuno Added as an example the *headband.* (Fering, that seemed the most relevant and weird of the stat-boosting items; I didn't think pointers were needed to all of them, for instance. I hope that's acceptable.) Also, I'm not a *4e* guy, so I can only speak back from *Pathfinder* to *D&D 3.5e* and earlier, and in those games there was typically no attuning (with exceptions for the *ring of sustenance* and the like).

Answer (score -3):

I can provide only a proof by contradiction that magic items function before they've been equipped for 24 hours.

Assumed for Contradiction: An item does not function without first being equipped for 24 hours.

Given: [Belt of Giant Strength](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-giant-strength/)

Belt of giant strength implies that it has effects before 24 hours have passed, but does not explicitly state it *grants* the referenced temporary ability bonus.

Therefore, we can conclude one of two possibilities:

1) The item at no time grants the temporary ability score bonus provided for in the item description, per the assumption for contradiction.

or

2) The item grants the temporary ability score bonus that it provides for during the first 24 hours of its being worn.

Now this is where you get into some RaI territory, wherein we must suppose a designer would not introduce a rule which was never actualized in practice. This would lead us to reject the first outcome. If you do so, we arrive at a contradiction, which yields the conclusion that the negation of our assumption is true, which is:
An item does function without first being equipped for 24 hours.

Furthermore, if there is not a rule in the text stating that items must or must not be worn for some amount of time before taking effect, proving either assertion false directly will be difficult due to the lack of falsifiability inherent in such a system.

Comment: Sorry, but I think your logic  is flawed. The text specifically says '...grants the wearer an enhancement bonus...' - there is no timeframe mentioned. It goes on to say 'Treat this as a temporary ability for the first 24 hours...' So, it's always the same bonus, it doesn't actually change, but is treated differently during the first day.

Comment: Well, yes. I never claimed it granted a different bonus.But to be treated differently on the first day, it would have to be treated at all on that day (e.g. not ignored). Therefore this item, at least, must function in some capacity (a limited one) during "the first 24 hours of being worn". This contradicts the supposition present in a universe where "items needed to be worn for 24 hours before they work".